# The main thread is not waiting until all the ThreadPoolExecutor threads finishes

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

The threads created by ThreadPoolExecutor are returning after first iteration in the for loop. The main thread is not waiting until the whole for loop finishes. Further checking I realised if I replace re.sub with just some dummy prints to stdout the loop is executed completely. What is wrong with using re.sub() in thread?

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading


def process_file(file):
    with open(file, 'rb+') as in:
        mm = mmap.mmap(in.fileno(),0)
        for i in range(len(global_list)):
            mm = re.sub(global_list[i], global_ch_list[i],mm)

    with open(file, 'wb+') as out:
        out.write(mm)


def process_all_files(files):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(process_file, files)


process_all_files(files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code has various error inside but muted, in order to see the error, you need consumer the returned iterator of `Executor.map`, quoted from the manual:

> If a func call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised when its value is retrieved from the iterator.

for example:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    results = executor.map(process_file, files)
    print(list(results))
```